# Helplessly lost with openCV and HoughCircles

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect this black circle [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clpR6.png). Shouldn't be too difficult but for some reason I just get 0 circles or approximately 500 circles everywhere, depending on the arguments. But there is no middle ground. Feels like I have tried to play with the arguments for hours, but absolutely no success. Is there a problem using HoughCircles and black or white picture? The task seems simple to a human eye, but is this difficult to the computer for some reason?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('temp.png')
output = image.copy()
blurred = cv2.blur(image,(10,10))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.5, 20, 100, 600, 10, 100)


if circles is not None:

    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        print len(circles)

    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    show the output image
cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([output]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: You are trying to draw the circle on the `gray` image. Try drawing it on the original color image.

Comment: Moreover, you are showing the `output`, which is a copy of the input image....

Comment: Sorry, I have been changing the code during troubleshooting to see how changes effect the processed image and managed to copy incomplete code here.

Still print len(circles) has never been 1.

Comment: I am formulating an answer Hold on

Comment: Have you come across [THIS DOCUMENTATION](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) It works perfectly for your image

Answer (score 1):

There are few minor mistakes in your approach.

Here is the code I used from the documentation:

```
img = cv2.imread('temp.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cimg1 = cimg.copy() 

circles = cv2.HoughCircles img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,255,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles.jpg',cimg)
```

[image]

```
joint = np.hstack([cimg1, cimg])  #---Posting the original image along with the image having the detected circle
cv2.imshow('detected circle and output', joint )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I had tried those settings earlier but it seems that this line: img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
is decisive. Without it the results are similar to mine. Would be nice to know why that medianblur is needed.

Comment: I hope you understand median in statistics. The same principle is applicable here.

Comment: Also try the different blur techniques given in the documentation. Apply all of them to one image and you will notice the difference

Comment: @m3h0w  I faced the same problem on numerous occasions :D