# Circle detection with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, computer-vision, feature-detection

How can I improve the performance of the following circle-detection code

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, scatter, show
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('points.png', 0)
_, image = cv2.threshold(image, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image = cv2.Canny(image, 1, 1)
imshow(image, cmap='gray')

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 32)
x = circles[0, :, 0]
y = circles[0, :, 1]

scatter(x, y)
show()
```

with the following source image:

[image]

I have tried adjusting the parameters of the `HoughCircles` function but they result in either too many false positives or too many false negatives. In particular, I am having trouble with spurious circles being detected in the gap between the two blobs:

[image]

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if you think it was helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Carlos, I'm not really a big fan of Hough Circles in situations like the one you've described. To be honest, I find this algorithm very unintuitive. What I would recommend in your case is using `findContour()` function and then calculating mass centers. Thus said, I tuned the Hough's parameters a bit to get reasonable results. I also used a different method for preprocessing before Canny, since I don't see how that thresholding would work in any other case than that particular one.

Hough method:
[image]

Finding mass centers:
[image]

And the code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, scatter, show, savefig
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('circles.png', 0)
#_, image = cv2.threshold(image, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image.copy(), (27, 27), 0)
image = cv2.Canny(image, 0, 130)
cv2.imshow("canny", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
imshow(image, cmap='gray')

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 22, minDist=1, maxRadius=50)
x = circles[0, :, 0]
y = circles[0, :, 1]

scatter(x, y)
show()
savefig('result1.png')
cv2.waitKey(0)

_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # compute the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    #draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (125, 125, 125), 2)
    cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 3, (255, 255, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imwrite("result2.png", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Both methods require some more fine tuning but I hope that gives you something more to work with.

Sources: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654568/helplessly-lost-with-opencv-and-houghcircles-python) and [pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/).

Comment: Hough transform gets unreliable when there are many circles close together, because parts of different circles combine to give the likelihood of a new circle. As @m3h0w has shown, you can tun the Hough parameters and also use more advanced features like contours and moments. The key thing is to either preprocess images before Hough transform, or post-process the results after the transform, or do both.

Comment: @m3h0w Aha another master stroke. Wish there was an option to *favorite* the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to fine-tune Hough Circles for a given image, the optimal parameters from image to image may vary alot. Hence, it takes quite some effort to make the circle detection robust using Hough Circles, though its doable!

Instead I would suggest to use more modern approaches like:

- Arc Adjacency Matrix-Based Fast Ellipse Detection (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8972900). Code available: https://github.com/Li-Zhaoxi/AAMED
- Circle Detection by Arc-support Line Segments ( https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8296246 ). Code available: https://github.com/AlanLuSun/Circle-detection