# Detecting circles in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-recognition, hough-transform

Though I realize that there is no "one size fits all" setting for OpenCV's `HoughCircles`, I'm having quite a bit of trouble finding even one reasonable set of parameters.

My input image is the following photo, which contains some pretty obvious big black circles, as well as some noise around it:

[image: Original input photo]

I tried playing with the `p1` and `p2` arguments, to try and get precisely the four black circles detected (and optionally the tape roll at the top -- that's not required but I wouldn't mind if it matched either).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

gray = frame = cv2.imread('testframe2.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
# gray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 2)

p1 = 200
p2 = 55

while True:
    out = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, param1=p1, param2=p2, minRadius=10, maxRadius=0)

    if circles is not None:
        for (x, y, r) in circles[0]:
            cv2.rectangle(out, (int(x - r), int(y - r)), (int(x + r), int(y + r)), (255, 0, 0))
            cv2.putText(out, "r = %d" % int(r), (int(x + r), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3, (255, 0, 0))

    cv2.putText(out, "p: (%d, %d)" % (p1, p2), (0, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 4)
    cv2.imshow('debug', out)

    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
        break
    elif cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        p1 += 5
    elif cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
        p1 -= 5
    elif cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('w'):
        p2 += 5
    elif cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
        p2 -= 5

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It seems the best I can do is detect the big circle several times but not the small one at all, *or* get a *lot* of false positives:

[image: Best parameter setting: detects big circle multiple times but not the small one]

I've Read The F** Manual but it does not help me further: how do I somewhat reliably detect the circles and nothing but the circles in this image?

Comment: have you checked out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658653/circle-detection-with-opencv) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654568/helplessly-lost-with-opencv-and-houghcircles) by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bit of manual tweaking with the `HoughCircles` params, but this gives the result you're looking for. I've used the [OpenCV Wrapper library](https://github.com/anbergem/opencv_wrapper) which just simplifies some things.

```py
import cv2
import opencv_wrapper as cvw
import numpy as np

frame = cv2.imread("tape.png")

gray = cvw.bgr2gray(frame)
thresh = cvw.threshold_otsu(gray, inverse=True)
opened = cvw.morph_open(thresh, 9)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
    opened, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, param1=100, param2=17, minRadius=5, maxRadius=-1
)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.around(circles).astype(int)
    for circle in circles[0]:
        cv2.floodFill(thresh, None, (circle[0], circle[1]), 155)

only_circles = thresh.copy()
only_circles[only_circles != 155] = 0

contours = cvw.find_external_contours(only_circles)
cvw.draw_contours(frame, contours, (255, 0, 255), thickness=2)

cv2.imwrite("tape_result.png", frame)
```

I used `HoughCircles` to find just the centers, as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) note.

I then used `floodFill` to fill the circles. Note that the left-most circle is very close to the edge. If the image was blurred, the flood filling would go into the background.

Disclosure: I'm the author of OpenCV Wrapper. Haven't added Hough Circles and flood filling yet.